# What is lime-cured ginger in Worldwar series?

Tags: translation, harry-turtledove, worldwar-series

There is *"[lime-cured ginger](https://turtledove.fandom.com/wiki/Ginger)"* in Italian translation as *"zenzero tagliato con **la limetta**"*, which means **lime fruit**, but in Czech print there is *"**vápnem** ošetřený zázvor"*, which is ginger cured with **mineral lime**.
So there are two interpretations: pickling and bleaching. 
Suppose we are able to rule out other possibilities because they weren't as common at the time, so they would have needed some explanation.
The brownish color of the cured powder found in book IV may provide a small clue, but maybe even bleached powder could have darkened after some time.

Comment: An excellent question and one not (as far as I can tell) addressed in the English language version of the books. Both mentions merely refer to "lime" without additional commentary. It could easily be [pickling in slaked lime](https://www.healthline.com/health/calcium-hydroxide#pickling) or [pickling in lime fruit juice](https://allwaysdelicious.com/pickled-red-onions/)

Answer (score 6):

This almost certainly refers to the mineral, not the lime fruit. From https://www.bizencyclopedia.com/articles/view/6800/149

> Bleached ginger is produced by dipping scrapped fresh ginger in a slurry of slaked lime, Ca(OH)2, (1 kg of slaked lime/120 kg of water) followed by sun drying.
> As the water adhering to the rhizomes dry, the ginger is again dipped in the slurry. This process is repeated until the rhizomes become uniformly white in colour.
> Dry ginger can also be bleached by the similar process. Liming gives ginger a better appearance and less susceptibility to the attack of insect pests during storage and shipping.

Comment: In what sense does it "almost certainly refer to the mineral"? Ginger can also be cured in lime juice or any strong vinegar

Comment: @Valorum I'd call that lime-pickled ginger. Sure, pickling and curing both refer to preservation, but "cured" *tends* to imply that the end product is relatively dry, whereas pickles tend to be wet.

Comment: Pickled ginger can also be dried afterwards and powdered

Comment: The answer states: "...uniformly white in colour."
But Striking the Balance Ch.VII reads:
"...bowl full of brownish powder. ... Not only was it ginger, it was lime cured,..."

Comment: @exim Ok. You should add that quote to your question. I've never encountered lime-cured ginger myself, AFAIK, but I often use ginger in my cooking, both fresh and powdered. Finely chopped fresh ginger is a very pale brown, but soon turns a darker brown hue. Powdered ginger usually has a brownish tinge, and it wouldn't surprise me if lime-cured ginger gets that tinge when it's ground.

Comment: @PM 2Ring The question is whether it was about preservation, taste (or better ingestion), maybe even psychoactive potency.
It doesn't seem to me that preservation was the crucial point here.

Comment: @exim Sorry, I can't see any mention of preservation, taste, ingestion, or psychoactivity in your question. If you want those factors addressed you should edit your question to make that explicit.